# Rock Paper Scissor Array Not Working Discord.js V12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to build an RPS game in my Discord bot. I want to add the functionality that if the word you choose does not exist in the `list`, it will return a message. This is my code so far:

```js
async execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord, profileData) {
  if (!args.length)
    return message.channel.send('To keep it fair, also send your pick!'); //If you don't
  //send a second
  //argument.

  const list = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissor']; // What the bot accepts.

  const rps = ['Rock! - ⛰', 'Paper! - ', 'Scissor! - ✂']; // Where the bot can
  // randomly pick from
  const random = rps[Math.floor(Math.random() * rps.length)];

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (message.content.includes(list[i])) {
      // If it does exits,
      // just execute the
      // command.
      message.channel.send(random);
      break;
    } else {
      message.channel.send(`\`${args}\` is not a valid option.`); //Return if the
      //argument you are
      //sending does not exist
      //in the list.
      break;
    }
  }
},
```

I thought this would work, and already did many other variants of this one. But still, even though for example `paper` is in the `list`, it still sends me ".. is not a valid option". It only works with `rock`. So what I want here is that if you send anything other than the values inside the array, it returns.

To make it short, I have two questions:

1. How can I fix this issue?
2. If I capitalize the values in the list (`Rock`), will it still work if I send `rock`?

Here is the link to my problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5AUp.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use a `for` loop. Instead of checking the whole `message` again, you only need to check the first argument (`args[0]`). You can simply use `Array#includes` and to make it case insensitive, convert this argument to lowercase. Your `list` already includes lowercase letters only, so the following will work:

```js
async execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord, profileData) {
  if (!args.length)
    return message.channel.send('To keep it fair, also send your pick!');

  const list = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
  const rps = ['Rock! - ⛰', 'Paper! - ', 'Scissors! - ✂'];
  const random = rps[Math.floor(Math.random() * rps.length)];

  if (!list.includes(args[0].toLowerCase())) {
    return message.channel.send(`\`${args[0]}\` is not a valid option.`);
  }
  // args[0] is valid
  message.channel.send(random);
},
```

[image]